# Wrap first 3 items ONLY in div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I'm pulling in content to li's dynamically using ASP.NET. In the ul I want to wrap a div class around the first 3 li items of the list only. e.g.

```
                <ul class="wrapper">
                    <div class="recommend">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                    </div>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
                </ul>
```

The closest I've found to getting this result is a fiddle I found and edited. http://jsfiddle.net/ZuK4E/ but it does every 3 instead of just the first 3 only. All lis are the same so cant target any with ids.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuK4E/1/)

```
$('ul.wrapper > li:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="recommend"></div>');
```

`lt(3)` will select `first three` elements as index starts from `0`.(i.e 0,1,2)

[**:lt**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty approach, I am trying for a better one.
Till then use this :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 3) {
if (i < 1) {
    a.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div class="recommend"></div>');
}
}
```